# Disposable Using Pattern

Tags: c#

```
  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path))
  {
    // do something
  }
```

Now I know the using pattern is an implementation of IDisposable, namely that a Try/Catch/Finally is set up and Dispose is called on the object. My question is how the Close method is handled.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) says that it is not called, but I have read otherwise.

I know that the FileStream inherrits from Stream which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx). Now that says not to override Close() because it is called by Dispose().

So do some classes just call Close() in their Dispose() methods or does the using call Close()?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `using` statement *only* knows about `Dispose()`, but `Stream.Dispose` calls `Close()`, as [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx):

> Note that because of backward
>   compatibility requirements, this
>   method's implementation differs from
>   the recommended guidance for the
>   Dispose pattern.  This method calls
>   Close, which then calls
>   Stream.Dispose(Boolean).

Comment: aww dammit, I've been Sleeted

Comment: Alright, this is what I thought from the documentation. Thanks Jon.

Comment: @George: Don't you mean Skeeted?

Comment: And also I apparently can't type.

Comment: btw: I've seen weird bugs before where filestreams opened with a using statement are still locked by the file system long after even the program quits.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Jon, I read this on your CSHARP faq today; what a coincidence!
P.S. I just ordered your book C# in Depth! looking forward to it.

Comment: @Joel: Sounds unlikely to me. I'd need to see evidence. If it's locked after the *program* has quit, it would have to be an OS bug, or a different process. Virus scanner perhaps? That can certainly have nasty effects.

Comment: @Michael: Cool, please send me feedback on the book. I love hearing from readers - in particular, please let me know if you spot any mistakes, however trivial! (Likewise any suggestions for clearer explanations...)

Comment: @Joel That is actually what this is related to. My guess is that it has more to do with static methods than strange behavior from the using statements.

Comment: @Joel: are you sure that the program wasn't still running? Have you checked the task manager to confirm that? If the program had improperly terminated threads, it may have 'hang' without you noticing it.

Comment: using is an alternative of try and finally block, but finally doesn't execute always (in case of unhandled exception), So using will also not work in case of unhandled exception?

Comment: @ShobhitWalia: Could you clarify what you mean? For example, https://gist.github.com/jskeet/56a1742ca2f7247c31503996c43216f9 prints both "In try block" and "In finally block".

Comment: @JonSkeet, As far as I know finally block will never execute in few condition, for example when (stackoverflow exception occur), since using is just a abstraction of try and finally the same will be true in that case, Is my statement correct?

Comment: @johnSkeet, As you already shared using statement only knows about Dispose method, Is there any way in which I can let him know the other user defined function?

Comment: @ShobhitWalia: (Firstly, please don't email me - keep the discussion here.) StackOverflowException is *very* special - your previous comment implied this was for unhandled exceptions *in general*. As far as I know there's no way of performing any kind of recovery in the face of a StackOverflowException. And no, the `using` statement can't be configured to call a different method.

Comment: Ok @JonSkeet I will never email you.

Answer (score 7):

using calls Dispose() only.  The Dispose() method might call Close() if that is how it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Close() is not part of the IDisposable interface so using has no way to know whether it should be called or not. using will only call Dispose(), but intelligently designed objects will close themselves in the Dispose() method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the using calls Close(), it would have no way of knowing that it should call that particular function.  So it must be calling dispose, and that in turn is calling close.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net classes Close() call Dispose(). You should do the same.