# Are resources disposed even if an exception is thrown in a using block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, using-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Dispose method still get called when Exception is thrown inside of Using statment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518352/does-dispose-method-still-get-called-when-exception-is-thrown-inside-of-using-st)

I've got a number of `using` blocks, when accessing a database. I was wondering - if an exception had to be thrown within the using block, would the necessary resources still be disposed, even though the end of the block is not reached? Or would I need to close them myself manually in the `catch` block?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The resources defined with the `using` statement were disposed, this is the main reason what `using` is good for.

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called **even if an
>   exception occurs** while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: +1 for the link to the description and being 15 sec. faster than me. ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Just waiting for timer to accept answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the resource of the using block will be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't. Actually the `using` block is the same if you use `try{}catch{}finally{}` construction with Dispose method call in the finally block. So it will be called anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the element will be disposed of, as the call is part of the `finally` block of the `try` into which the `using` translates.

From 8.13 of the C# specification:

> A using statement is translated into three parts: acquisition, usage,
>   and disposal. Usage of the resource is implicitly enclosed in a try
>   statement that includes a finally clause. This finally clause disposes
>   of the resource. If a null resource is acquired, then no call to
>   Dispose is made, and no exception is thrown.

So you won't need to dispose of it manually, and I'm unsure of where your own `catch` block would be in this case anyway.