# Multiple using block c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, using, using-statement

I am working on application in which i need to access database. Use of using statement is good because `"using" statement is to ensure that the object is always disposed correctly, and it doesn't require explicit code to ensure that this happens.` So i am little bit confused where to use "using" and where to not.

```
public int route(Route r)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("",con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any time an object you create implements `IDisposable`, disposing of it (with or without the `using` syntactic sugar) [is a good idea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx#remarksToggle).

The benefit of the `using` block syntactic sugar (over manual `.Dispose()` calls) is that `Dispose()` will [still be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518352/does-dispose-still-get-called-when-exception-is-thrown-inside-of-a-using-stateme) even if there is an exception and flow leaves the using block.

Also, note that you can stack up the usings, without nested indentation:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("",con))
using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader()) // Still need to open connection ...
{
   ...
```

As an aside, a further benefit of `using` is that if the `IDisposable` variable is declared within the `using`, it that the variable [is `readonly` and cannot be reassigned within the block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), e.g.:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
{
   sdr = new SqlDataReader() // Error
```

Comment: If i am not using nested indentation then how will i ensure that the object disposed correctly because object is disposed at the end of block.

Comment: @HotCoolStud don't worry.Compiler will take care of that.It is smart enough to understand that you want nested statements and that's why it's a valid syntax.

Comment: I had no idea one could do that! :D But I sure hope you are right that the compiler will dispose of objects in a LIFO-kind of order because this could be a problem otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify it like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("",con))
using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
{
     ...
}
```

Using statements are translated to `try/finally` blocks.Therefore your object will be `Disposed` even if there is an exception thrown.So if you have a Disposable object and you want to ensure that it will be Disposed after it's used, you can use `using` statements.Remember it's kind a syntactic sugar for this:

```
SqlCommand cmd;
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    ...
}
finally
{
   ((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks okay as far as `using` blocks are concerned.

However, you should NOT use a `try/catch` block here, unless you intend on actually doing something with the exception. Otherwise you are just hiding possible errors away, which is dead wrong.

Comment: Pokemon exception handling... "Gotta catch em all". A very bad and very common code smell.