# SPSite currentSite using try/catch block

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, try-catch, using

What is a better approach when it comes to writing code for sharepoint 2010 applications:

```
 using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
 {
     using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
     {
        try{...}
        catch{...}
     }
 }
```

or

```
try 
{
  using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("SiteName"))
  {
     using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
     {
        ....
     }
  }
}
catch{...}
```

?
Thank you!

Comment: They both do different things, which is "better" depends on which behavior you want for your application.  Neither is better without context.

Answer (score 0):

from a similar thread( [Does Dispose still get called when exception is thrown inside of a using statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518352/does-dispose-still-get-called-when-exception-is-thrown-inside-of-a-using-stateme) )

the top rated answer there suggests that both examples you gave will be alright considering resources disposal:

> `using` wraps your code in a try/finally block where the finally portion will call `Dispose()` if it exists.

so the remaining concern might be the resource acquisition, which might throw exceptions as well(been working with sharepoint for a couple of years now and seemingly everything in this framework is throwing exceptions at you sooner or later). so i'd suggest using your second example to catch those.